# How to insert in a wordpress page a widget that shows days since a specific order was made?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have to output this information but I am not used to work with PHP, don´t know what I am doing wrong.

I query woocommerce order date like this:

```
$order = wc_get_order(456);
$orderdate = $order->date_created;
```

That seems to be working ok, it returns a date in this format:

```
2020-10-15T17:38:37-03:00
```

For current date, I create a variable like this:

```
$date = date('d-m-y h:i:s');
```

But when I try to output the difference in days between order date and current, it always give me 0

This is how I tried to calculate the difference:

```
function dateDiff($date1, $date2)
{
    $date1_ts = strtotime($date);
    $date2_ts = strtotime($orderdate);
    $diff = $date2_ts - $date1_ts;
    return round($diff / 86400);
}

$dateDiff = dateDiff($date1, $date2);

echo ("day difference is: " . $dateDiff  );
```

Thanks a lot for reading, hope you can help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short explanation of what is wrong with your code:

```
$dateDiff = dateDiff($date1, $date2);
```

In your case `dateDiff` is a function which expects two parameters `$date1` and `$date2`. But you are passing non existing variables to the function. They do not exist out of the function scope, because you didn't declare them.

Then you are trying to get timestamps from dates which are in parent scope and probably getting NULL as a result from both cases :)

```
$date1_ts = strtotime($date);
$date2_ts = strtotime($orderdate);
```

Small improvements:

Its better to use [DateTime](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) class when you are working with dates. DateTime class has powerful method called **format** that allows you to output date in suitable format for you.

If we combine what you did into one piece of code with some changes, then we will get this:

```
$order        = wc_get_order(456);
$order_date   = new DateTime($order->date_created);
$current_date = new DateTime();

function dateDiff($date1, $date2)
{
    // check if diff is not equal to zero in order to avoid division be zero exception
    if ($diff = abs(strtotime($date2) - strtotime($date1))) {
       return round($diff / 86400);
    }

    return 0;
}

echo ("day difference is: " . dateDiff(
    $current_date->format('d-m-Y h:i:s'), 
    $order_date->format('d-m-Y h:i:s')
) . " days");
```